# How to build spotyxbmc2 for the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: merge, cross-compiling, spotify, xbmc, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to build spotyxbmc2 for the Raspberry Pi. My first attempt was to just cross-compile the source code from spotyxbmc2's Github, but it turns out that the XBMC code needs to be modified for it to compile correctly and use the OpenGLES library compatible with the Pi's GPU. So I then tried to git merge the code from xbmc-rbp (Raspberry Pi compatible XBMC branch) with spotyxbmc2 code. It all seemed to work at first. I had the libraries for the Pi and the Spotify specific code from spotyxbmc2. When I tried to compile I ran into some errors, like missing "}" or random "====" or ">>>>>" inserted into the code. After cleaning it up I managed to compile everything, but when make tries to build a binary it fails almost immediately with erros saying that there are a lot calls to undefined functions in the code. I have no idea what I did wrong. Does anyone have any idea?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> random "====" or ">>>>>"

They're `git` merge conflict markers. If you didn't deal with those properly (and not to be mean, but if you didn't recognise them as conflict markers I doubt you did) you'll have all sorts of problems.

I'd advise starting again from scratch, this time dealing with merge conflicts properly. If you don't know how to deal with merge conflicts, there's a ton of tutorials online.

After that, if it still fails, you need to provide code for us to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yes this was the first time I merged two repositories with git. Sorry if didn't state that at first. I will start again by learning how to deal with merge conflicts first. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @supernova32 It might be easier to use openELEC. They are currently creating a port for the Raspberry Pi. A tutorial can be found at http://openelec.tv/component/k2/item/241-openelec-meets-raspberry-pi-part-1

Comment: @TheLukeMcCarthy Thanks for the suggestion, but I already tried it and the kernel has no support for the wireless adapter I'm currently using. I know I can recompile the kernel, but I'm going to try to get this done first. If I fail then I will try to compile OpenELEC with Spotify support and wireless modules.

Comment: @supernova32 Good luck, I hope it works for you. Also don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check this [spotimc](https://github.com/mazkolain/spotimc/downloads)

Which is a complete spotify addon for xbmc works pretty well and may solve your problems :).

Answer (score 0):

As of 26 Jan 2013, Spotyxbmc for Raspberry Pi is available in OpenELEC. Use the compilation instructions in the spotify thread on their forum. The port was made by kernevil.